When a null uncountable set can be image of some increasing function with discontinuities on a dense countable set
Consider the following result:

A: Let $f:D \to \mathbb R$ be an increasing function with discontinuities on a dense countable subset of $D$ such that the jump values sum to $\mu(D)$, where $D$ is a bounded interval of reals. Then, the image of $f$ is a null uncountable set.

Any function $f$ satisfying the initial conditions of A is strictly increasing (more details can be found here). Using A, one can flexibly generate null uncountable sets. Due to this level of flexibility, I am wondering if a converse of A is also correct, that is,

B: Any null uncountable set (such as Cantor set) is the image of some [increasing] function $f:D \to \mathbb R$  with discontinuities on a dense countable set where the jump values sum to $\mu(D)$.

You may help to prove B (generally or under some conditions e.g., by relaxing the assumption that $f$ is increasing) or give a counterexample. In particular, can the Cantor set be obtained this way?
Update 1.
As discussed in comments, $f(D)$ in A is always Borel. On the other hand, the Cantor set, which is Borel, cannot be the image of a strictly increasing function. Hence, all Borel null uncountable sets cannot be the images of some strictly increasing functions.
Now there are two questions
1- What properties characterize a null uncountable set that is the image of a strictly increasing function?
2- Which null uncountable sets can be the image of an interval under a function with a countable set of discontinuities?
In comments, @bof presented a way of constructing a function with a countable set of discontinuities whose image can be any closed null uncountable set (such as the Cantor set). @bof also showed that all null uncountable sets cannot satisfy the second since the number of null uncountable sets $2^{\mathfrak c}$ is strictly larger than the number of images $f(D)$, which is $\mathfrak c$.
Analytic sets are the continuous images of Borel sets, for which  interesting results are known, e.g., a Borel set is characterized as an analytic set whose complement is analytic. Here we deal with those sets that are the non-continuous images of Borel sets under functions with countable sets of discontinuities.

There are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ uncountable null sets but only $2^{\aleph_0}$ increasing functions.

The Cantor set can't be the image of a strictly increasing function $f$ defined on an interval. If $f(a)=\frac13$ and $f(b)=\frac23$ what would $f(\frac{a+b}2)$ be?

Just as an illustrative example of what we can do, consider the Cantor staircase function $f$ and let $g$ be its “inverse” where for each dyadic $r$ (i.e., every “step” of the staircase) we let $g(r)$ be the smallest $x$ such that $f(x)=r$ (and for non-dyadic $y$ we let $g(y)$ be the unique $x$ such that $f(x)=y$). Then the image of $g$ is the Cantor set minus the right endpoints of all the components of its complement.

(Similarly we can get the Cantor set minus the left endpoints of all the components of its complement. But as bof points out in their comment, we necessarily have to omit one of the two. So as far as the Cantor set goes, this is the best we can do.)

An increasing function is Borel. If it is strictly increasing then it is injective, and the image of an interval under an injective Borel function is a Borel set. So, your condition cannot include null sets which are not Borel.

@NateEldredge Thank you! In this answer, Michael showed that the image was Borel. As your proof is different, I just added it here.

The Cantor set is Borel and cannot be the image of a strictly increasing function. Hence, all Borel sets cannot be the images of some strictly increasing functions. Can any null uncountable set be the image of an interval under a function with a countable set of discontinuities?

A linearly ordered set is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ if it is nonempty, dense-in-itself, has no least or greatest element, has a countable dense subset, and is Dedekind complete.

There are $2^\mathfrak c$ uncountable null sets, but there are only $\mathfrak c$ pairs $(D,f)$ such that $D$ is an interval of real numbers and $f:D\to\mathbb R$ has a countable set of discontinuities. (Note that the function $f$ is determined by its values on a countable denset subset of $D$ which includes all the points of discontinuity.)

@bof Thank you for the interesting observations! Do you expect such images can be characterized?

If $A$ is a nonempty closed subset of $\mathbb R$, we can define a surjection $f:\mathbb R\to A$ so that $f(x)$ is one of the nearest points to $x$ in $A$. Then $f$ has a countable set of discontinuities, namely, one discontinuity in each bounded component of $\mathbb R\setminus A$

An open subset of $\mathbb R$ has countably many components. This is because the components of an open set are open sets, and every nonempty open set contains a rational number.

@bof A nice construction that also shows that the Cantor set can be the image of a function with a countable set of discontinuities. The number of closed null uncountable sets is $\mathfrak c$?

A function with a countable set of discontinuities is a Borel function: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369268/a-function-with-countable-discontinuities-is-borel-measurable?rq=1 The image of a Borel set under a Borel function is an analytic set. But there are many null uncountable sets that are not analytic. For instance, analytic sets are universally measurable, so take any set that is null for Lebesgue measure, and non-measurable for the completion of some other Borel measure.
